# Visual Studio Code - remote-ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

i would like to establish a connection with a linux  machine from my host machine windows  where i install VSC using remote-ssh

here's my configuration file

```
Host 192.168.1.18
  HostName 192.168.1.18
  User my-user-name
  IdentityFile D:/KEY/id_rsa.pub
```

and when I log in I get the following error message

```
could not establish connection to 192.168.1.18 bash not found
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is your linux distribution ?